# How to get the length of a identifier/method in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, metrics, code-metrics, software-quality

I'm trying to get the length of all the identifiers and methods of a project made in ASP.NET Core 2.2, in order to analize the code metrics for a homework, but I haven't found any kind of tool that provides that metric.

By far I've used Code Metrics of Visual Studio 2019, and I got the next metrics:

- Maintainability Index
- Cyclomatic Complexity
- Depth of Inheritance
- Class Coupling
- Lines of Code

I wanna know if there's any tool that provides me the metric that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tool [NDepend](https://www.ndepend.com/) to compute the `identifierLength` metric. NDepend also supports many more [code metrics](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics).

For example you can write this [C# LINQ code query](https://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL). You can try yourself with the full featured trial available for download.

```
from m in Application.Methods
select new { m, identifierLength = m.SimpleName.Length }
```

[image: code metric identifier Length with NDepend]

*Disclaimer: I work for NDepend*

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using the reflection API, you can get all Types in the assembly with `Assembly.GetTypes()`.

For each type you can get all methods with `Type.GetMethods()`.

For each method you can get the `MethodBody` with `MethodInfo.GetMethodBody()`.

You can then call `GetILAsByteArray()` on each `MethodBody` to get the IL as a byte array.

This is raw bytecode, but you could use the length of that byte array as a metric.

If you want to analyse the code as C#, you will need to disassemble it from IL with something like Reflector.